# Split string by comma but not comma within number R

Tags: r, regex

I have a string that looks like:

`a <- "900, 1,100, 1000"`

I want to split the string by commas that are not within a number to obtain:

`"900" "1,100" "1000"`

I can split using all the commas `b <- strsplit(a, ',')` however this gives me the output `"900" "1" "100" "1000"` which I don't want.

Comment: Split by `,[ ]` because that's all there is. The space is the delimiter not the comma, this just removes the comma. For example try splitting with just a comma with this `900,1,100,1000`

Comment: For the example you have, you can just split on `", "` with a space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this should be easy if you include the space in the pattern:

```
b <- strsplit(a, ', ')
```

Comment: That's right, @x15. Replies on SO are often concurrent. Do you really think that a peek at the comments was necessary to answer this?